# laravel 4 : insert new recode into a one to one relational tables using eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, model, relational-database, eloquent

ex:
there are two tables which are related each other one to one
one table is users other one is students

**users-**
primaryKey-'uid',name,age

**students-**
primaryKey-'std_id' , faculty , gpa

and this is the model for students table

```
class Student extends Eloquent {
protected $table = 'students';
protected $primaryKey = 'std_id';
public $timestamps = false;

public function User(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
}
```

this is the model for users table

```
class User extends Eloquent {
protected $table = 'users';
protected $primaryKey = 'uid';
public function Student(){
return $this->haveOne('Student');
}
}
```

and I want to know how to insert new recode with keep relationship between tables

```
$user = new User();
$user->name= Input::get('name');
$user->age= Input::get('age');
$user->save();

$student= new Student();
$student->faculty = Input::get('faculty');
$student->gpa= Input::get('gpa');
$student->save();
```

**error msg ►**

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or  update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

above code is not working and may I use push() instead of using save()
how ?
I would really appreciate any help :)

Comment: Where's the foreign key in your tables?

Comment: this is the student table sql query above table structure is simplified for clearance 
 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `career`.`student` (  
  `comp_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,  
  
  `user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`std_id`),  
  
  CONSTRAINT `fk_industry_users1`  
    FOREIGN KEY (`std_id`)  
    REFERENCES `career`.`users` (`uid`)  
    ON DELETE NO ACTION  
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models) actually explain it all.

Just use the `save()` method on the relation:

```
$user = new User();
$user->name= Input::get('name');
$user->age= Input::get('age');
$user->save();

$student= new Student();
$student->faculty = Input::get('faculty');
$student->gpa= Input::get('gpa');

$user->Student()->save($student);
```

Or the other way around with `associate()`:

```
$user = new User();
$user->name= Input::get('name');
$user->age= Input::get('age');
$user->save();

$student= new Student();
$student->faculty = Input::get('faculty');
$student->gpa= Input::get('gpa');
$student->User()->associate($user);
$student->save();
```

Oh and also it's **has**One() not haveOne()